# How much different is windows and linux in network programming?

Tags: windows, linux, network-programming

I'm reading `<<Understanding Linux Network internals>>`,but not sure how much of it will also apply to windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will find that they are very similar as both are based on the standard [Berkley sockets API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets).  Assuming you are programming in C here, you'll see the same sorts of functions with similar usage in both windows and unix (listen, accept, bind, etc).

There are of course many windows-specific socket functions though, mostly for things like async IO.  Here's a list of the [Windows socket functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741394%28VS.85%29.aspx) so you can have a look for yourself.

Comment: In your link I saw `winsock` and `winsock2`,what's the main difference and which one should we use now?

Comment: winsock2 is just the current version of winsock.  It's backwards-compatible with the original winsock, but just adds additional functions and behavior (mostly for dealing with protocols other than TCP/IP)